# mysql query with all columns plus count one certain column

Tags: mysql, select, count

Trying to figure out if I can reduce my mysql queries to decrease the amount of connections to the database. Is their away to pull all the rows and then just count a certain row where is matches a certain string such as:

```
mysql_query(
    "SELECT *, (COUNT(unread = 1) AS msgsunread) 
          FROM message_received WHERE user_id = '$uid'");
```

Comment: If you're doing a `SELECT *` anyway, then you can just perform the count yourself while looping through the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.  If you extend the count statement in your example into a full subquery, you'll get:

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM message_received WHERE unread = 1 AND user_id = $uid) AS unread_count,
FROM message_recieved WHERE user_id = $uid;
```

Which'll have the unread count you're looking for (in every row!).  MySQL should be smart enough to cache the result of that count query, too, so you've effectively performed two queries over one connection.

Having the count tagged onto every row does seem a bit excessive, though...  Maybe this is a place where two queries is just a better bet - and you can try to optimize elsewhere with joins, or something else that MySQL is less of a nuisance about - counts are a pain in the dominant buttock.

Hope this helps!

**PS:** If this is PHP, you should be able to perform any number of *queries* over a single *connection* - just call `mysql_query(...)` a bunch of times before calling `mysql_close(...)`.

Comment: Well I have pretty much joined everywhere else, was just seeing if this was possible, for some unfortunate reason ipage is horrible and limit the amount of mysql query connections from a user at one time, so i was trying to eliminate as many as possible, trying to hold off until my contract is up to switch somewhere else.

Comment: @Bobby - Gotcha.  Maybe jswolf19 has the best answer for you, then; if you're getting all those rows anyway, you can just count them yourself.  Also - how irritating!  Best of luck with that...